# How do you set object prop and return object in one line?

Tags: javascript

I've got this code:

```js
const arr = [{name: 'fred', age: 20}, {name: 'john', age: 50}]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.name] = item.age
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

How do I make the following 2 lines into 1 line?

```
 acc[item.name] = item.age
 return acc
```

Comment: Why? You're doing two distinct things. Making it look like one thing will only make your code harder to understand.

Comment: `acc[item.name] = item.age; return acc` will do it though.

Comment: `return {...acc,[item.name]: item.age}` if u want

Comment: Or use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). Or for a new object `=> ({ ...acc, [item.name]: item.age })`. But there's no problem with the current code.

Comment: `arr.reduce((acc, { name, age }) => ({ ...acc, [name]: age }), {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to combine `item` with your new key/value, then use `({})` to directly return the object:

You could also use the [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get `name` and `age` as separate variable in stead of `item`, see commented line for an example.

```js
const arr = [{name: 'fred', age: 20}, {name: 'john', age: 50}]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [item.name]: item.age }), {})

// Or with a destructuring assignment
// arr.reduce((acc, { name, age }) => ({ ...acc, [name]: age }), {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: worth mentioning, this creates a new object and avoids object mutation. great answer thx and it fixed another totally unrelated problem I was having too!